# How to defer javascript from within the functions.php file without losing all styling?

Tags: php

I would like to increase performance of wordpress site by deferring javascript on the site. However, when I do this, it loses all styling. Is there a way to be more specific on which styles to render and not?

I'm using the below code in a functions.php file to implement this. It seems to work, but the website loses all of it's stylings:

```
function defer_parsing_js($url) {
//Add the files to exclude from defer. Add jquery.js by default
    $exclude_files = array('jquery.js');
//Bypass JS defer for logged in users
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (false === strpos($url, '.js')) {
            return $url;
        }

        foreach ($exclude_files as $file) {
            if (strpos($url, $file)) {
                return $url;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
    return "$url' defer='defer";
}

add_filter('clean_url', 'defer_parsing_js', 11, 1);
```

Is there a better method I do not know about? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why that code would interfere with your styles.  I've used almost the exact same code/process and it shouldn't have any impact on stylesheets.

Comment: Is it possible that it's deferring assets from the theme, which would include stylesheets?

Comment: This line `if (false === strpos($url, '.js')) {` essentially checks to ensure a file is .js, and if it isn't it just returns as is.  So it shouldn't effect .css files.  Are any of your styles dependent on javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Try this instead (and I can put it in an answer if you want better formatting, but this technically isn't answering your question, rather giving you an alternative.):
`function defer_js( $url ) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return $url; //don't break WP Admin
  if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
  if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
   return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $url );
 }
 add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_js', 10 );`